# Should I implement getStream on Back-End or Front-End?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework, getstream-io

I'm building my own social network service like Instagram. I'm using React Native for Mobile Front-End and Django RESTful Framework for BackEnd.

In my case, should I implement getStream for my feeds and notification on Back-End or Front-End? (Django-python or React-Native JS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recommend using a back-end system to communicate with Stream. Putting logic in the front-end system (or React native) means you'd be storing your API credentials in a public-facing app or in a mobile app, which is easily reverse-engineered.